# Why is my bubble sort producing duplicate values?

Tags: c, bubble-sort

I've started learning C last month and I am stuck with a question, my bubble sort algorithm is somehow producing duplicate values and I can't figure out why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void BubbleSort(int numarr[]) {
    int j, k, t;
    for (j = 20; j > 1; j--) {
        for (k = 0; k < j - 1; k++) {
            if (numarr[k] > numarr[k + 1]) {
                t = numarr[k]; numarr[k + 1] = numarr[k]; numarr[k + 1] = t;
            }            
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numarr[] = {
         2,  3,  5,  7, 12, 11, 13, 24, 17, 19,
        36, 23, 29, 52, 31, 37, 68, 41, 43, 84
    };
    BubbleSort(numarr);
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numarr[i]);
    }
}
```

This is the output I am getting is:

```
2
3
5
7
12
12
13
24
24
24
36
36
36
52
52
52
68
68
68
84.
```

Can you guys help me?

Comment: First of all, please don't try to cram as much as you can onto a single line. That makes the code very hard to read and follow.

Comment: But more importantly, remember that array indexes are *zero* based. That means an array of `20` elements will have indexes from `0` to **`19`**. Your code will go out of bounds, and lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: Also please don't hard-code [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) (like the `20`). Add another argument to the function for the number of elements. That will also make the code clearer, and also lower the risk of using incorrect values.

Comment: Your outer loop is wrong. Why are you looping 20 times? You should loop only until no values are swapped in the inner loop. This then requires you to set a flag to false at each iteration of the outer loop and set it to true whenever a swap occurs. Continue the outer loop while the flag is true. A second note, you should pass the number of elements in the array as a second parameter to your BubbleSort function rather than using a fixed number within the array.

Answer (score 1):

The swap code isn't right.  The posted code is:

```
t = numarr[k];numarr[k+1] = numarr[k];numarr[k+1] = t;
```

It should be:

```
t = numarr[k];numarr[k] = numarr[k+1];numarr[k+1] = t;
```

This might be more clearly written as:

```
t = numarr[k];
numarr[k] = numarr[k+1];
numarr[k+1] = t;
```

Comment: Oh, I feel so stupid now, thnx tho :)

Comment: @Rachit If you put the statements on separate lines, it would have been *much* easier to see that you use `numarr[k+1] = ...` twice.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Now I get what what you meant

Answer (score 0):

The bug comes from your swapping code: you update `numarr[k+1]` twice and do not change `numarr[k]`.

It is recommended to write a single statement per line, and it would have made the mistake more obvious.

Note also that you should pass the number of elements of the array to the `BubbleSort` function, instead of hard coding a length of `20`.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void BubbleSort(int numarr[], int len) {
    for (int j = len; j > 1; j--) {
        for (int k = 0; k < j - 1; k++) {
            if (numarr[k] > numarr[k + 1]) {
                int t = numarr[k];
                numarr[k] = numarr[k + 1];
                numarr[k + 1] = t;
            }            
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    int numarr[] = {
         2,  3,  5,  7, 12, 11, 13, 24, 17, 19,
        36, 23, 29, 52, 31, 37, 68, 41, 43, 84
    };
    int len = sizeof(numarr) / sizeof(numarr[0]);
    BubbleSort(numarr, len);
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        printf("%d\n", numarr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```